# aptitude: Meaning of curly brackets, i.e. package1{b} package2{a} package3{u}

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

When using **aptitude**, the list of changed packages sometimes has a single character in curly brackets behind some package names. The man-page has two examples of them but does not explain them (version 0.6.10-1).

I have noticed {b}, {a} and {u} so far. The former one seems to show up when running `aptitude install` and tries to re-install packages I deleted (e.g. via debfoster, how can I disable that?), the latter two seem to have something to do with automatic dependency resolution.

What do these characters mean, are there others, and what implications do they have for other operations? Is that extra information available to `dpkg` or `apt`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These aren't documented. My guess is that `a` is for an automatic install, `u` is for an (automatic?) upgrade and `b` is for packages installed to fix broken packages.

This would mean `debfoster` is removing packages it is not supposed to, note that the website says:

```
As of 2006-01-01, debfoster is officially deprecated.
```

Possibly this has developed bugs over the years due to changes in the `apt` system. You could confirm this by doing `aptitude search '~b'` after using `debfoster` (it will list broken packages).

Note that `apt` now supports an automatic flag for dependency packages and has `apt-get autoremove`. With aptitude you can also do `aptitude remove '~g'`.

#### Update

Playing around with aptitude, it turns out that if I press `?` when I get the `Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]` prompt, I get the following message:

```
In the list of actions to be performed, some packages will be followed by one or
more characters enclosed in braces; for instance: "aptitude{u}".  These
characters provide extra information about the package's state, and can include
any combination of the following:
  
  'a': the package was automatically installed or removed.
  'b': some of the package's dependencies are violated by the proposed changes.
  'p': the package will be purged in addition to being removed.
  'u': the package is being removed because it is unused.
```

So it seems that `b` is supposed to be for a broken package. Although, in your case it seems to be a bug that it is displayed if there is nothing broken. I can't recreate the issue, but `aptitude` does try to reinstall packages I remove with `apt-get` just without anything in braces.

Also note that `aptitude keep-all` is probably safer than removing `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates`

Comment: `ps auxf` shows that debfoster just calls `apt-get --purge remove pkg1 pkg2 etc.`, search '~b' returns nothing, and the next `aptitude install` reinstalls pgk1 pkg2 etc.

Comment: @finitegraygreen, I guess its not for broken packages then! You could try using `aptitude why` to find what is happening or just the `--show-why` option.

Comment: @finitegraygreen, what was the the conclusion here? Was `b` for broken after all or did `aptitude why` turn up some other reason? I'm sure I will come across this again at some point, would be nice to know...

Comment: Well, the conclusion is "These aren't documented." And I stopped the interference between apt-get and aptitude by forcing amnesia on the latter via deleting `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates`.
Otherwise I'd still get `apt-get remove pkg; aptitude why pkg` "Unable to find a reason to install"; `aptitude install` then installs pkg.

Comment: @finitegraygreen, turns out there is a description of what these mean. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/blog/entry/aptitude-0.4.10-released/) by the aptitude author explains `{a}` and `{u}`:

- `{a}` means that the package will be additionally installed besides what you asked for.
- `{u}` means that the package is not being used by the system and will be removed.

Unfortunately it doesn't explain `{b}`.